# Put the current time into a long

Tags: java, android

```
public void Clik(View view){

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    long seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    TextView calenderTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    String myTime = (String) String.valueOf(calenderTest);
    calenderTest.setText(myTime);

}
```

This app uses a button to get the current time, puts it into a long, and displays it. However I am receiving an output I was not expecting.

[image: Error Received]

Comment: Wow! What a insightful request! Wish I could help you out, but I don't have the know-how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to use? :)

```
long seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
TextView calenderTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
String myTime = (String) String.valueOf(seconds);
calenderTest.setText(myTime);
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for the help! It worked like a charm!